# Unity UNET How to change online scene in sync with clients

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, unity3d-unet

I'm using the old Unity 2017.3 UNET implementation in my game.  Players connect to a server and are placed in a Lobby scene until the party leader selects another level to go to.  The implementation is just a slightly modified version of the default NetworkLobbyManager.

The trouble started now that I've begun heavily testing the networking code by running a compiled build for a client and then using the editor as the server.  Very frequently, the server running in the editor will run a great deal slower than the compiled client build.  So when I use `NetworkManager.ServerChangeScene` the client will load the scene before the server, which will cause all NetworkIdentities on the client scene to be disabled (because they haven't been created on the server yet.)

It's a lot less likely to happen if the server is running a compiled build, because the server will almost always load the scene before any clients.  But it does surface a bigger issue with Unity itself.  That there's no guarantee that the server will be available when changing scenes.

Is there some other way of changing scenes in a networked game?  Is there a way to guarantee that the server enters the scene before any clients?  Or am I stuck just kind of hoping that the network remains stable between scene changes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Additive scene loading in Unity Networking-UNet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909305/additive-scene-loading-in-unity-networking-unet)

Answer (score 0):

Well I thought about it more overnight and decided to look in other directions, because more investigation revealed that sometimes the Network Identities are still disabled when the server loads the scene first as well.

I was looking through the [UNET source code](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/networking/src/3610ab4e4c0f2a3d74bb3d005641e11201c7e6f3/Runtime/NetworkServer.cs?at=5.3&fileviewer=file-view-default) and realized that the server should be accounting for situations where it loads the scene after the clients, although that code looks a little jank to me.  This theory was backed up by the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetSceneObjects.html) I found that also says NetworkIdentities in the Scene on startup are treated as if they are spawned dynamically when the server starts.

Knowing those things now, I'm starting to think that I'm just dumb and messed some stuff up on my end.  The object that was being disabled is a manager that enables and disables other NetworkIdentity objects.  I'm pretty sure the main problem is that it's disabling a network identity on the client, that is still enabled on the server, which is causing the whole thing to go haywire.

In the future, I'm just going to try and stay away from enabling and disabling game objects on a networked basis and stick to putting relevant functionality behind a flag of my own so that I can "soft disable" an object without bugging out any incoming RPCs or SyncVar data.